# jquery json and php mysql on submit check

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

After I submit my form I want to retrieve some data from MySQL through an ajax request but I have some problems with my getJSON function.

This works:

```
$("form[id=bilddatenbank_sortiment_anlegen]").submit(function() {
    var array_sortimentsname;
    $.getJSON('inc/inc.sortimentsname.php', function(array_sortimentsname) {
        console.debug(array_sortimentsname);
    });
    return false;
});
```

I need to access `array_sortimentsname` outside of the `getJSON` function, how would I do this?

Comment: Have you set the headers in php to `text/json`? Also make a new variable like `var parsedJson = null;` and in the function to get the json you can do someting like `parsedJson = array_sortimentsname;` and then you can access it outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("form[id=bilddatenbank_sortiment_anlegen]").submit(function() {

    var array_sortimentsname;
    var parsedJson = null;

    $.getJSON('inc/inc.sortimentsname.php', function(array_sortimentsname) {

        parsedJson = array_sortimentsname;
        //console.debug(array_sortimentsname);

    });

    console.debug(parsedJson);

    return false;

});
```

Like this? I get an my console: null

Yes, I have edited the header.

Answer (score 1):

Okey, with this code, I got on the first submit null and after my second submit my data. Sync problems?

var array_sortimentsname;
var parsedJson = null;

$("form[id=bilddatenbank_sortiment_anlegen]").submit(function() {

```
$.getJSON('inc/inc.sortimentsname.php', function(array_sortimentsname) {

    parsedJson = array_sortimentsname;
    //console.debug(array_sortimentsname);

});

console.debug(parsedJson);

return false;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a variable outside of the Ajax function, so you can access it when the result come form the server. Something like this:

```
let sortedData = null;
$("form[id=bilddatenbank_sortiment_anlegen]").submit(function() {

    $.getJSON('inc/inc.sortimentsname.php', function(array_sortimentsname)
    sortedData = array_sortimentsname
    console.debug(array_sortimentsname);
});

return false;
});
```